# Understanding a cost function

Tags: change-point

I have been analyzing a cost function used in a point of change algorithm.
I am having trouble understanding the notion of a cost function and how it generates results for example.

```
import numpy as np
i_variance_2 = 1 / (variance ** 2)
cmm = [0.0]
cmm.extend(np.cumsum(data))
cmm2 = [0.0]
cmm2.extend(np.cumsum(np.abs(data)))
def cost(start, end):
    """ Cost function for normal distribution with variable mean
    Args:
        start (int): start index
        end (int): end index
    Returns:
        float: Cost, from start to end
    """
    cmm2_diff = cmm2[end] - cmm2[start]
    cmm_diff = pow(cmm[end] - cmm[start], 2)
    i_diff = end - start
    diff = cmm2_diff - cmm_diff
    return (diff/i_diff) * i_variance_2

return cost
```

I have taken this code from [changepy](https://github.com/ruipgil/changepy)

Now what are the cumulative sums for and why am I take the absolute value of the cumulative sums denoted by *cmm2*.

Finally I am trying to understand why you multiply by  *i_variance_2* at the end of the cost of function

I have introductory knowledge in statistics so i have been slowly building my knowledge back up.

Comment: You might be better asking on a coding site.

Comment: I feel like even though there might be code, it is more about the algorithm presented. The code can be commented or written out to be in a more formal presentation. Cost on a coding website would mean a completely different thing too.